# Jenkins- How to merge two git branch and then build the merged branch

Tags: git, github, jenkins

In Jenkins how to merge two git branches as provided in the field:

branch_names to build: `branch_name1, branch_name2`

image added

and (if there was not conflict) then build the merged branch

I tried multibranch deployement but it does not meet my expectated usecase

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the branch you want to merge into:

```
git checkout <branch_to_merge_into>
```

Merge the other branch into the current branch:

```
git merge <other_branch>
```

Resolve any conflicts that may arise during the merge process.
Commit the merge:

```
git commit
```

Once the merge is complete, build the branch using your preferred build method.

Push the merged branch to the remote repository:

```
git push origin <branch_to_merge_into>
```

Comment: I do not want to do this manually everytime. Developer will provide two branch names seperated by comma in Jenkins as a parameter and these steps (merge those 2 branches and build the merged branch) will be performed by Jenkins

Comment: then you can work with this single command: 
" git checkout <branch_name> && git merge <branch_2_name> && git push origin <branch_name> && git build <branch_name> "

Answer (score 0):

Use Jenkins Plugins- git and merge  and create job as parameterized job(Two parameters)

[image]

Create two string values one with Source and Destination to pass it from parameters

[image]

Configure SCM git plugin with required credentials and add Branches to build section as shown (pass values as per parameter key values)

[image]

Use post Build option

[image]

Above configurations works for me.

ref: https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/#plugin-content-publisher-push-merge-results